# Is there a conditional css statement specific for Outlook Mobile?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm designing an emailer and since I'm having issues with Outlook, I made Outlook (for desktop) specific styles which worked for me well... I'm using this to apply my outlook styles:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> html/css styles here <!--<![endif]-->
```

and filter them:

```
<!--[if !mso]> html/css styles here <!--<![endif]-->
```

The remaining problem is the Outlook Mobile. How can I target Outlook Mobile? Example:

```
<!--[if (!mso) | (.outlook-mobile-only) ]>
```

It seems that Outlook Mobile recognizes the `!mso` statement and ignores my mobile specific styles.

Answer (score 2):

No and yes.

There is nothing specifically targeting Outlook Mobile. Outlook desktop for the most part does not read @media queries.

Outlook for Android does not use @media queries. Outlook for Mac does, but most versions of Outlook do not work with them.

For more information, check out:
https://cm.engineering/fixing-bugs-with-outlook-specific-css-f4b8ae5be4f4

This is a good follow-up:
https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/

Good luck.